# "Broken packages" do not let me install packages

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm having some problems trying to setup a mjpg-streamer in my raspberry pi running raspbian. When I was trying to install the package, the following error was appearing:

**sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libjpeg8-dev' instead of 'libjpeg-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) but 8d1-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've looked a lot of suggestions on google, and tried things like **apt-get update** and **dpkg --get-selections | grep hold** (nothing shows up). I really tried a lot of stuff, with no luck.

Do anyone have any suggestion on what to do?

Thanks everyone

Comment: You need [`libjpeg8`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libjpeg8) as a dependancy.

Comment: I already have libjpeg8 installed, do I need to do anything else? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As been said, it is a dependency problem, to solve it you can use aptitude.

To install aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

To use aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install package_name-normaly_dev
```

Comment: more info regarding how to install ImageTk can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170806/8609386

Comment: After running `sudo aptitude install my_package_name`, I then have to choose `no`, `yes`, `yes`, for my particular case, to choose to downgrade the troublesome package. Then it works.