# cannot import name 'ImageTK' - python 3.5

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load in an image from the same folder as the one my python script is in.

```
# create a class called Person
# create init method
# 2 attributes (name, and birthdate)
# create an object from the Person class

from PIL import Image, ImageTK
import datetime
import tkinter as tk

# create frame
window = tk.Tk()

# create frame geometry
window.geometry("400x400")

# set title of frame
window.title("Age Calculator App")



# adding labels
name_label = tk.Label(text="Name")
name_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

year_label = tk.Label(text="Year")
year_label.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

month_label = tk.Label(text="Month")
month_label.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

day_label = tk.Label(text="Day")
day_label.grid(column = 0, row = 3)


# adding entries
name_entry = tk.Entry()
name_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)

year_entry = tk.Entry()
year_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

month_entry = tk.Entry()
month_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

day_entry = tk.Entry()
day_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)


def calculate_age():
    year = int(year_entry.get())
    month = int(month_entry.get())
    day = int(day_entry.get())
    name = name_entry.get()
    person = Person(name, datetime.date(year, month, day))
    text_answer = tk.Text(master=window, wrap=tk.WORD, height=20, width=30)
    text_answer.grid(column= 1, row= 5)
    answer = "{name} is {age} years old!".format(name=person.name, age=person.age())
    is_old_answer = " Wow you are getting old aren't you?"
    text_answer.insert(tk.END, answer)
    if person.age() >= 50:
        text_answer.insert(tk.END, is_old_answer)


calculate_button = tk.Button(text="Calculate Age!", command=calculate_age)
calculate_button.grid(column=1, row=4)


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthdate):
        self.name = name
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def age(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        age = today.year - self.birthdate.year
        return age

image = Image.open('LockVectorDaily.jpg')
image.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=image)
label_image = tk.Label(image=image)
label_image.grid(column=1, row=0)


window.mainloop()
```

I got

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTK 
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTK'
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: How did you install PIL? There’s something wrong with the installation.

Comment: The "k" is lower case, ImageTk.  Caps/lower case get a lot of people in Tkinter/tkinter.

Answer (score 68):

For Debian/Ubuntu:

Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging python-pil.imagetk
```

Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk
```

For Archlinux:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pillow
```

It will install the package and you can use it: `from PIL import ImageTk`

Comment: This is for Debian/Ubuntu users. I think the `ImageTk` part is included in the windows version of the `Pillow` module (fork of PIL). For Archlinux users, the install command is `sudo pacman -S python-pillow`.

Comment: For some reason `apt` can always handle this dependency BS itself whereas Python cannot

Answer (score 10):

For Python3 on Ubuntu 18 I had to uninstall the Python (2) packages then install the Python 3 packages:

```
apt-get remove python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk python-pil.imagetk python-pil
apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk # Note that python3-pil installed as a dependency
```

Comment: For me, installing `python3-pil.imagetk` was enough.

Comment: The PIL version supplied by `apt install python3-pil` is (5.1.0), i.e. is dated, and I did not find `python3-pil.imagetk` is installed in Ubuntu 18.04. Note that PIL and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) cannot coexist, and Pillow should be used instead, and it is version 7 presently. So after uninstalling PIL via the `sudo apt remove` command, you should install PILLOW via `python3 -m pip install --user Pillow`. It will also ensure that `ImageTk` can be imported.

Comment: The first command deleted some unnecessary things please use it with caution

Answer (score 5):

I tried this to install Pillow itself and it works well, i didn't use sudo.

```
$ pip install Pillow --user
```

Source for the main installation guide: [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Feel free to edit my answer/correct me.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Issue is that you named it wrong.

ImageTK instead of ImageTk

keep the **k** small, and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change the code like this:

```py
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
```

It should work fine!

Answer (score 2):

Python does act up a little when importing TkImage and Image together. You need to import the PIL first and then import TkImage and Image individually like below-

```
import PIL
from PIL import TkImage
from PIL import Image
```

This should work fine. You can also check if the pillow is installed in your system correctly by using command prompt like below-

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Type **python**
3. Once you are in python, just type :

```py
import PIL
```

4. If this command doesn't throw any errors, then you are good to follow the above method of importing TkImage and Image separately.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 3.6.9
 `import tkinter, PIL` 
when I open the tkinter module directly , using dir(tkinter) , I see PhotoImage and Image methods .
I check the PIL module, dir(PIL) I don’t see
any of the above mentioned methods.

I suppose no need to import PIL ...
It’s already in the tkinter module.
So you could use tkinter.PhotoImage(...)
Or tkinter.Image(...)

Answer (score 0):

The simple trick is to write them separately and not on a single line.

```
 import PIL
 from PIL import TkImage
 from PIL import Image
```

Answer (score -6):

Got it figure out!
You must import them separately and not on one line.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
```

Insead of

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Comment: Both cases are equivalent. It works because you replaced the 'ImageTK' of the question by 'ImageTk' which is the right name.