# PIL.ImageTk import and/or installation error

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, python-imaging-library, python-import, importerror

When I get to my beloved Spyder console and it welcomes me with

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
```

I go on and type this:

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image
```

And it goes and shows another line like everything was right.
Then, on the next line, I type this:

```
In [2]: from PIL import ImageTk
```

And it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-47edf18ebb7f>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk

ImportError: cannot import name ImageTk
```

Okay, this means I should have a problem with my libraries. No sweat.
A fellow programmer had a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835909/cannot-import-name-imagetk-python-3-5), and:

1. I am sure there are no typos in my import
2. Ubuntu reports the python-imaging package as up-to-date:
3. Ubuntu reports the following on the python-imaging-tk package:

These Bash lines:

```
python-imaging is already the newest version (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1).

<more bash lines />

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-imaging-tk : Depends: python-imaging (= 1.1.7-4) but 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
```

This is the juiciest part. When I go back to Spyder and type to get the version of PIL.Image, it returns this:

```
In [3]: Image.VERSION
Out[3]: '1.1.7'
```

I am at a loss here. Please send help.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging=1.1.7-4
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

solved the problem.

It still bothers me **why** but at least my dependencies are working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

this just solved my problem. This is for python 2.7