# Having problems with the ImageTk module

Tags: python

[image of IDE with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxoyh.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image

expression = ""

def press(num):
    global expression

    expression = expression+str(num)
    equation.set(expression)

def equalpress():
    try:
        global expression
        result = str(eval(expression))
        equation.set(result)

        expression = ""
    except:
        equation.set("Invalid Equation")
        expression=""

def clear():
    global expression

    expression=""
    equation.set("")

if __name__=="__main__":

    window = Tk()
    window.configure(background="red")
    window.title("Simple Calculator App")
    window.geometry("280x300")

    equation = StringVar()

    expression_field = Entry(window,textvariable=equation,font=("Aerial",20),fg="red")
    expression_field.grid(columnspan=10,ipady=10,ipadx=70)

    width = 50
    height = 50

    img1 = Image.open("ferra.gif")
    img1 = img1.resize((width,height))

    oneImage = ImageTK.PhotoImage(img1)
    button1 = Button(window, image=oneImage,bg='red',command=lambda:press,height=height,width=width)


    button1.grid(row=2,column=0)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show the code and the error as text (not as image), and [ask an actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'ImageTK' - python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835909/cannot-import-name-imagetk-python-3-5)

Comment: Please don't pictures or links to pictures of code or errors.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem with the pillow module, I had the same issue while using any function of pil module. Uninstalling the pil package and reinstalling it again helped me. So just try these commands in your terminal.
'''
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
'''
Hope this will help you.