# Updating gpgmepp from 1.13 to latest (at least 1.19)

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-20.04, poppler, gpgme

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to add a digital certificate to Okular to sign pdfs. [Okular requires Poppler to be at least version 21.01](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular/signatures.html), to add digital certificate signature, but the Poppler version that shipped with this is 0.86.1. So I've been trying to update the Poppler version, [following very helpful instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636441/pdf2image-library-failing-to-read-pdf-signed-using-docusign/74313286#74313286).

When trying to run `cmake -DTESTDATADIR=./test -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/man ..`, I got an error about not finding a package configuration file provided by "Gpgmepp", that it could not find the 1.19 version of Gpgmepp.

So I tried to install gpgmepp with `sudo apt-get install libgpgmepp-dev`, but that installs version 1.13.1 which seems a little outdated.

I'm not quite sure how exactly to update libgpgmepp to the latest version (or at least 1.19), I tried going to the [GnuPG website to download the latest binary release](https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html), which is a GnuPG Desktop AppImage with the current GnuPG, and tried to run it, but I'm not sure what that's done. When I run `cmake -DTESTDATADRIR=./test -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/man ..` again, the error is still the same

```
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Gpgmepp" that is
  compatible with requested version "1.19".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Gpgmepp/GpgmeppConfig.cmake, version: 1.13.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Gpgmepp/GpgmeppConfig.cmake, version: 1.13.1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:168 (find_soft_mandatory_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:162 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find the 1.19 version of Gpgmepp.  If you're not interested in
  the features it provides set the cmake ENABLE_GPGME option to OFF
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:168 (find_soft_mandatory_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jocelyne/poppler-23.11.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

When I run `gpg2 --version`, the output is

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/jocelyne/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cypher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

If anyone would point me to how I can update gpgmepp to >1.19 (if gpgmepp is different to gnupg, I'm not entirely sure of this), or how I can tell cmake to use the updated gnupg, so that I can eventually get Poppler to be updated to the 23.11 version, that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should try compile and install gpgme yourself, same way you're doing for Poppler, you can find instructions on how to compile gpgme on their git repo (see README and INSTALL files):

https://github.com/gpg/gpgme